# How to troubleshoot lack of google analytics data from my web site

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

I have an ASP.NET MVC project on somee.com and have tried for a few days to integrate the Google Analytics tag I got in a Java Script file, but I can not see any data in the dashboard. I have tried everything from adding the script to the bundle to adding it as a partial page. I have cleared the browser cache a few times, but nothing seems to work. I am using the .net framework version 4.6 and here is the relevant configuration lines from web.config file:

```
...
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
...
```

I have added the following lines to the BundleConfig.cs file:

```
Bundle preMinified = new Bundle("~/bundles/gtag").Include("~/Scripts/gtag.js");

            bundles.Add(preMinified);

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Here are some relevant lines in the _Layout.csthml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/gtag")
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript,Software,Developer,.Net,C#,Windows Presentation Foundation, WPF, ASP.NET MVC,PHP,JQuery">
    <meta name"author" content="Owner" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Saman M.A.</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Html.Partial("_GoogleAnalytics")
```

When I load the page, I see the script, and I used the "Send Test Traffic" button under tracking code, and it loads my page ok. I sent an email to the provider asking if they block the analytics traffic to Google, given that my account is free, and they have an analytics service offering but I have not received a response.

I also added a couple of GoogleAnalytics nuget packages, they seem relevant, but I do not know if they need any added configuration. I could not find the documentation for them. Is this even possible? I see so few tutorials or previously asked questions about this. Should I be looking at doing this on Azure application insight or a similar service because it is Micorosoft technology?
Here is what is in my Java Script file. It is called gtag and it is in the 
/scripts folder.

```
//< !--Global site tag(gtag.js) - Google Analytics-- >
<div>
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-151742661-1"></script>
<script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};}
        gtag('js', new Date()); 
        gtag('config', 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID');
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        try {
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("my code");
        pageTracker._trackPageview("/");
    } catch (err) {}
    </script>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-151742661-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() { 
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
    </script>
    //<!--Google Analytics-- >
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-151742661-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
       // <!--End Google An
```

How can I fix or troubleshoot this issue?
[Git Public Repo for this project](https://github.com/bitflame/BoootstrapDemo.git)

Comment: there are several redundant analytics JS snippets all messed up. I'd suggest you remove all the unnecessary codes and keep in line with the recommended install guide https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs

Comment: Thanks. I will. I know what you are referring to. The redundant code is the result of several attempts including different variations of adding Google code alone. As you may know one way is to bundle the script, and the other way is to add it to the _Layout.cshtml file, and yet another one is to just add it to every page.